# How to ensure inheriting classes do not break base class contract in the context of LSP?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, liskov-substitution-principle

In C# - but it may be applicable to other languages - in the context of [LSP](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/lsp.pdf), how can I ensure that a class inheriting from another (mutable) one will not break the original contract?

For example:
If I have `public`, `internal` or `protected` property setters, there is a risk that inheriting classes will break the original contract.
The same is applicable for `virtual` methods.

This is especially true if the owner of the parent and inheriting classes are not the same persons as it may introduce a lack of knowledge in the contract and in the intention of the original developer.

Is immutability the only one solution or are there some other ways of doing?
I tend to consider that inheritance corresponds to a "behaves like a"-relationship instead of a "is a"-relationship. Is it a correct logical safeguard?

Here's an example for the sake of illustration:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual void DummyMethod(int dummyParameter)
    {
        if (dummyParameter > 10) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(); }
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override void DummyMethod(int dummyParameter)
    {
        if (dummyParameter < 0) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
    }
}
```

I noticed some other questions dealing with this topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10778354/how-can-i-avoid-beaking-liskov-substitution-principle-lsp) for example) but I'm looking for general solutions or good practices to apply to avoid facing these issues upfront.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "behaves like a"? On a related note, how would you expect to stop classes from violating a contract when implementing an interface? (The same kind of answers quite possibly apply to this case...)

Comment: For example a square _is a_ rectangle but _does not behave_ the same way (as per the link to the article in my question).

Comment: For the interface implementation, I don't know. Actually I didn't really think of this as the interface does not have any contract beyond its own signature - at least in C# - so it's enforced by the compiler. In a class, I may be throwing an exception in one of the method for example but nothing indicates it from outside.

Comment: How can a derived class break the contract? The public and internal methods don't change (they still exist with the same signature). And behavior is supposed to change with each derived class; that's polymorphism. What are you looking to prevent?

Comment: There is only one good way: use the *sealed* keyword.

Comment: @BobHorn see the example I just added. The exception thrown in the subtype is not a subtype of `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. If I don't own the parent class and the exception in the parent class is not documented, do I have any way to avoid such breach in the contract?

Comment: @HansPassant So you mean as soon as inheritance is allowed, and the behaviour of a class can be extended, we don't have any way to avoid violation of LSP?

Comment: @Guillaume This isn't a violation of LSP. The subtype can still be used in place of the base type. Yes, the behavior is changing, but that's okay. That's polymorphism.

Comment: I don't know Java, but I believe you can specify the types of exceptions that will be thrown within a method. C# doesn't have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent violation of the LSP by using the `sealed` keyword.

This means you now can't inherit from this class at all, so you have to decide which you prefer: eliminating the risk of violating the LSP or the freedom to inherit and modify.

Credit to @Hans Passant for first mentioning sealed in comments.